# expressJS + MongoDB Update - add element to array field if not exists,

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

i want to add element into array field of found element if it doesn't already exist. How to do it in ExpressJS + MongoDB?

My document schema:

```
{ "name" : "Paul",
 "year" : "2013",
 "artist" : "SomeArtist", 
 "moods" : [  "angry",  "furious" ],
 "_id" : ObjectId("526fe5676f066d0353000002") }
```

I want to add element into moods array if it doesnt already exist.
How to do it in expressJS?

I've already coded a function, which allows to add element into array:

```
exports.setMood = function(req, res) {
var nameWhere = req.body.name;
var newItem = req.body.mood;

db.collection('tracks', function(err, collection) {
    collection.update({ name: nameWhere }, { $push: { moods: newItem } }).toArray(function(err, items) {
        if (err) return res.send(500, err);
        res.send("OK");
    });
});
```

};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [$addToSet](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) for that:

So in your example:

```
  collection.update({ name: nameWhere }, { $addToSet: { moods: newItem } }).toArray(function(err, items) {
        if (err) return res.send(500, err);
        res.send("OK");
    });
```